# Add a span tag in the href tag, that includes href tag's text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tags

Im trying to do something like that`<a>text</a> ---> <a><span>text</span></a>` with jQuery. But i don't get the result, that i want. Can you help me out please?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: `jQuery('#id').find('a').append('<span></span>');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/):

http://jsfiddle.net/E2hsd/

```
$('a').wrapInner('<span/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrapInner:

```
$('a').wrapInner($('<span/>'));
```

https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/